# Error Handling Server 500 Errors in Java App

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch, http-error

I'm trying to not just use the `catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}` and give the users of the application a bit more clarity into why my application may be failing.

Hence, I want to detect if a given server error was thrown, like Http 500 error for instance.

Currently, my code is throwing a stack trace with:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500
```

within the catch block below:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
            String UrlToParse = "theurlishereinmycode.com";
            parser.parse(UrlToParse);
            Document doc = parser.getDocument();

            // Get the document's root XML node
            NodeList PGRoot = doc.getChildNodes();

            // Navigate down the hierarchy to get to the program node
            Node comp = getNode("ProgramGuideWCSResponse", PGRoot);
            Node PG = getNode("programGuide", comp.getChildNodes() );
            Node Programs = getNode("programs", PG.getChildNodes() );
            Node IndivdualProgram = getNode("program", Programs.getChildNodes() );

            //String execType = getNodeAttr("programTitle", exec);

            // Load the executive's data from the XML
            NodeList nodes = IndivdualProgram.getChildNodes();
            String showTitleAttr = getNodeValue("programTitle", nodes);

            // check to make sure the fetched Show Title isn't: 1) null or 2) blank
                // if it is... display the default value for title.
                // else, print the Program Title.

            if(showTitleAttr == null || showTitleAttr == ""){
                System.out.println("You’re watching XX Plus");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Program title is: " + showTitleAttr);
            }
        }

        catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

How can I log a HTTP 500 Error for Internal Server error?

Thank you

Comment: Are you having troubles with how to present the error message or how to find out it's an HTTP 500?

Comment: How to find out if its a http 500 as in detecting if a 500 error is being thrown in the catch block

Comment: I guess this line `Document doc = parser.getDocument();` throws the exception. Maybe you should investigate if there (in getDocument) is a more specific exception than IOException being thrown. You could catch exactly that type then. Some HttpClients throw a "WebException" or something like that for example ...